# Can we use gmail API to access a collaborative inbox?

Tags: gmail-api, collaborative

I have tried to use Gmail API to access a personal mailbox, it works well, but is it possible to access a google collaborative inbox with Gmail API too? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Collaborative inbox seems to be of a different domain. There is no mention of such feature in [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/) on how to operate with them so the answer is No.